# Windows 10 uwp upload failing

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I've developed Windows 10 UWP app and I'm getting below error message when I upload package to Windows 10 store.

> "Unable to find the dependent appx packages
>   'Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00;Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2;Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1;'
>   with processor architecture 'x86' specified in the PackageDependency
>   section of the app manifest."

Comment: @magicandre1981 Store apps can be compiled as ARM, x86 or x64.

Comment: @RareNCool yeah, I overlooked the tags and thought he tries a winphone 8.1 store app

Comment: Can you add to the question the content from the `project.json` file in your app project? Also you have not mentioned what Windows 10 version you are using for build as well as VS2015 version (Update1/2/3?)

Comment: Also could you please open in text editor the `Package.appxmanifest` from the same app project and find the `<Dependencies>` section and copy paste here the dependencies you have? It could looks like:

    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10049.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10049.0" />

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing some package dependencies in your manifest. Here is an example of the format for a appx package WinJS dependency.

```
<Dependencies>
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.WinJS.1.0"
  Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
  MinVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
```

For the documentation on how to format dependencies see [PackageDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211454.aspx)

Comment: I'm using C#.net for my app not WinJS

Comment: WinJS is just an example you need the dependencies related to 

"Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00;Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.2;Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.1"